# Power regenerate after 3 seconds?

Tags: unity, c#, timer

I work on script that makes an object with a "sprite" power moves faster. Like "Dark souls". Here is my script:

```
private float sprit = 100.0f;
public float spritTime;
public bool spritsBool;

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && spritsBool == true) {
        spritTime --;
        Debug.Log(" run ");
    }

    if (spritTime >= sprit) {
        spritTime = sprit;
    }

     if (spritTime <= 0) {
        spritsBool = false;
        spritTime = 0;
    }
    else { 
        spritsBool = true;
    }

    StartCoroutine("wait_sprit");

} // end update

IEnumerator wait_sprit() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    spritTime ++;
}
```

It's counting over 100, not waiting for 3 seconds to regenerate. Help me please to solve this ?

Comment: The first thing to fix here is that you are calling "wait_sprit" every frame.

Comment: Not really clear what you want here. You want it to take 3 seconds to refill `sprit` if it's empty?

Comment: I downvoted because the code shown to us is not valid C#.

Comment: @Krythic, before downvoting, try some basic tests to ensure your own understanding is not invalid (this does get us all from time to time). The code *is* valid C#. Just to ensure my own understanding was correct, I copy pasted it into a script, and ran it in Unity. It works as far as counting up. This process took me 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want something that allows the object to move faster for a short period of time, then must wait before it can move faster again. The below script would allow you to move faster for 10 seconds, then require 3 seconds wait before again moving fast for 10 seconds.

```
private float maxSprint = 10f;
public float sprintTime;
bool resetting = false;

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && sprintTime > 0) {
        sprintTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log(" run ");
    }

    if (sprintTime <= 0 && !resetting) {
        resetting = true;
        StartCoroutine(wait_sprint());
    }

    sprintTime = Mathf.Clamp(sprintTime, 0, maxSprint);

} // end update

IEnumerator wait_sprint() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    spritTime = maxSprint;
    resetting = false;
}
```

Comment: you missed one thing. regenerate the sprint with time. 'spritTime = maxSprint;' I need it to count up after 3 seconds, NOT give me equal value. can you do this ?

Comment: So it needs to fill up over 3 seconds? And only starts refilling once it's empty? What if you only use a little bit, does it refill then after a delay?

Comment: No. before i used ++; it refill auto. not waiting to complete 3 seconds.

Comment: Yes but before it didn't work. Please answer the questions specifically so I can provide the code. Good code needs good requirements. You haven't specified good requirements.

Comment: Yes, before and now. to make it more clear, look at this [https://giphy.com/gifs/aGj55lTwVtNhS] Look at the green line and see how it refilling. I want to do the same but delay it (after 3 seconds).

Comment: Your gif doesn't work. And you didn't answer the three questions I asked in my first comment.

Answer (score -2):

You start that co routine every update meaning that, after a 3 second delay, you will be increasing spritTime once every frame. Perhaps you mean to be that coroutine in  the first if statement after you decreased spritTime